# jQuery: Wrap all elements in one div but not in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a question about `.wrapAll()`. So far I got this code:

```html
<div id="firstDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
</div>

<div id="secondDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
</div>
```

and I want another `div` wrapping the first set of accordions. So I tried it with:

```js
if ($('#firstDivContainer').find('.accordion').length != 0) {
  $(".accordion").wrapAll("<div id='accordionBox' />");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
</div>

<div id="secondDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
</div>
```

but he removes the accordions from the second set and adds them to the first set.
The result should be:

```html
<div id="firstDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div id="accordionBox">
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="secondDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
</div>
```

but instead I got

```html
<div id="firstDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div id="accordionBox">
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="secondDivContainer">
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
  <div class="element">stuff</div>
</div>
```

I guess the solution is just a minor change but I m currently stuck with this dratz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply narrow your initial selector, so you are only selecting `.accordion`s inside `#firstDivContainer`:

```
$("#firstDivContainer .accordion").wrapAll("<div id='accordionBox' />");
```

```js
$("#firstDivContainer .accordion").wrapAll("<div id='accordionBox' />");
```

```css
#accordionBox{
    background: #FCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDivContainer">
    <div class="element">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
</div>

<div id="secondDivContainer">
    <div class="element">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="accordion">stuff</div>
    <div class="element">stuff</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#firstDivContainer .accordion").wrapAll("<div id='accordionBox' />");
```

should do it.

Comment: why is this duplcated from above answer? seems to be pointless. -1